# Topological version of "If $A$ is compact and $B$ closed then $d(A,B)>0$"

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness

I have already proven that if $(X, d)$ is a metric space and $A, B \subset X$ such that $A$ is closed and $B$ is compact and $A\cap B = \varnothing$, then $d(A, B) > 0$. What I was wondering is that what (if any) would be the topological version of this statement? That is, what would be an analogous result in a topological space which is not metrizable?

Comment: There can be such version in topological vector spaces.

Comment: You might want separation axioms. A typical example would be that $A$ and $B$ are contained in open sets that do not intersect. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_axiom

Comment: There can also be such version in uniform spaces. I'm not familiar with this notion but came to my mind now.

Comment: @SortofDamocles Good observation! I am wondering that is the Hausdorff space coarsest well-known space in which this an appropriate analogue to this theorem exists? Or could such an analogue exist even in a Fréchet space?

Comment: If $X$ is Hausdorff and $A,B\subseteq X$ are disjoint sets such that $A$ is closed and $B$ is compact, then $A,B$ can be separated by disjoint open sets